# Who said differential dx is a very small quantity?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Given a differentiable function $f(x)$ in a point $x_0$, by definition, the differential $df$ is the difference in ordinates of the tangent line to curve in $x_0$, evaluated at the point $x_0 + dx$.
Now, $dx$ can be small or big, and if it is small enough, we know that this difference approximates: $f(x_0 + dx) - f(x_0)$.
Question is: it's $dx$ just a quantity which can be taken big or small? (often taken small enough in applications)?

Comment: It’s rare to use $dx$ as the name of a real number. One might use $\Delta x$ as the name of a real number. In the old days, nonrigorous treatments of calculus used to say that $dx$ is an “infinitesimal”. Then calculus was made rigorous, and so modern real analysis textbooks typically don’t mention “infinitesimals” at all. Often in analysis or smooth manifolds textbooks “$dx$“ is used as the name of  a particular differential form.

Comment: @littleO but from your answer it seems not wrong referring to $dx$ as a real number, isn't it? And if it is so, it can be not only infinitesimal but any number, right?

Comment: You can use $dx$ as the name of a real number if you'd like. And if you choose to do so, then yes there is no assumption that $dx$ is small. Personally I'd avoid using $dx$ as the name of a real number though.

Comment: @littleO ok, thank you. Still i cannot realize how the same symbol $dx$ can mean so many different concepts and seems not have a unique definition..

Comment: Have you read any of the MANY posts about the meaning of $dx$ of this site?

Comment: @Joe few of them but exactly as books and articles do, none seems to agree on a unique definition of what $dx$ actually should be interpreted. As you can see also in this post, the prevalent answer is: it depends on the context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the convention used in the book you are consulting. As an example, when you write $\int f(x) dx$, then the $dx$ does not have a proper meaning in itself, because one reads it all together with the notation $\int ... dx$. However, it is heuristically understood to be meaning infinitesimal portion along the $x$-axis.

In differential geometry, $dx$ is often used to indicate, for instance, the basis vector to the tangent plane to the manifold. Since such a plane will have a different basis for each infinitesimal movement along the surface of the manifold, geometrists and physicists decided to denote it like that, because it heuristically makes sense.

To sum up: it depends a lot on the authors of the books and what they want to convey with that notation.

Comment: i see. But how is it possible that the same symbol can mean so many different concepts?

Comment: Well, I agree with you that it is very annoying that they don't agree on the notation. However, I think we are kind of used to using the same notation for very different objects as, for instance, we use the symbol $x$ to denote very different things in different contexts; it can be a variable in some deterministic equation, the realization of a random variable in probability, an element in a set in some weird topology, an element of a ring in algebra... I can bet you can also find examples of such patterns.

Comment: @Giack_89 There are thousands of concepts in Mathematics. If we used a new symbol for each one, writing Mathematics would be a nightmare. Even the most common symbols have several meanings. For example $\pi$ is used to denote the Arquimedes constant, the prime counting function, the homotopy groups and prime elements in number fields.

Comment: @jjagmath ok, i see. But E.g. I can use the symbol  to represent the number 3.14... or even a plane, and that's ok, because it's the same symbol for two different concepts. Problem with $dx$ is: E.g. in integrals we have $dx$ used as just a symbol to know the variable we are integrating? Yes. But it can be also thought as a small amount to be summed? Can choose it small but also big. But it can be thought as a real number? Conceptually yes but in practice no. But it's the same $dx$ as difference in ordinates of the tangent line? Conceptually yes, in practice don't know... Such a confusion!

Comment: @Giack_89 the notation $dx$ can be informally thought of as an infinitesimally small change in $x$, and it's fine to think of it that way. It's the same $dx$ used in differentials and integrals.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be rigorous, but in a way, $dx$ can be represented as a quantity, but I like to see it as more of a change in the linear approximation using a tangent line on a curve. I wouldn't think of $dx$ as a "big quantity." It's more like a small $\Delta x$ that, when approaching $0$, gets closer to $dx$.

Note that $\Delta x$ is the difference between $x$-values and the original $x$-value. But $dx$ is the differential and it's an approximated difference between the $x$-values. For functions $y = f(x)$, the differential $dy$ is just an approximated change in the $y$-values by using the derivative.

In a standard calculus class, it's fine to think of $dx$ and $dy$ as infinitesimal quantities if you don't mind being informal and if you want to get a basic intuition.

Comment: Anyway in the basic Calculus class it is told: what is Δ? Consider $y = x$; differenciate both sides: $dy = dx$. But on the other hand we know: $dy = f'(x) Δ = 1 * Δ$. So $1 * Δ = dx$. Then in general case, when we differenciate a generic function f: $df = f'(x) Δ = f'(x) * 1 * Δ = f'(x) dx$. So Δ and $dx$ seem to be the same thing. (At least in this explanation..)

Comment: @Giack_89 $dy = f'(x) \Delta x$? Did you really see an equation written exactly like that in class? I wonder what it was supposed to mean.

Comment: @DavidK yea exactly like this. If you prefer you can write h (small or big as you like) in place of Δ and with the same argument go to same conclusion: i.e. h = dx. It doesn't change, the meaning is, as usual, that you are evaluating the differences in ordinates of the tangent line to the curve in $x_0$ considered at abcissae: $x_0 + Δ$ (or if you prefer $x_0 + h$), and $x0$ same thing.

Comment: If you change the left-hand side to $\Delta y$ and if $f(x) = ax + b$ for some constants $a$ and $b,$ then you have a correct equation. But it seems very strange to mix "$d$" notation with "$\Delta$" notation in this way. You could declare that $dx$ is the same thing that other people write as $\Delta x$ or $h,$ but then the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ means something quite different than how people use $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in most places in the world of mathematics.

Comment: @DavidK if i do as you say i would get: Δ = a Δ, i don't understand what's the point with this. Concerning  / , in fact this is just a notation for the derivative which comes from the differential definition $dy = f'(x) dx$ if you divide both side by $dx$. Problem is that rigorously you cannot divide by a differential! It's not an allowed operation, It's just a mnemonic notation, but personally i strongly diasapprove this notation for the derivative because indeed it is the result of an incorrect operation.

Comment: The original question was about what a differential is. It is not just a small number. On the other hand, typically $\Delta x$ is defined as a (possibly small) real number; it is not a differential. In short, $dx$ and $\Delta x$ have very different definitions in a standard calculus course, and the mixing and matching you showed is quite bizarre. Regarding the Leibniz notation, I don't ask you to like it; but understand that when mathematicans write it today, they do **not** mean that a differential $dy$ is divided by $dx.$